# Can't work out why Sub-Query returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, in-clause

I have the below data which is also in [**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cebce/16).

```
    CREATE TABLE completework
    (`id` int, `workerid` int, `checkerid` int);

    CREATE TABLE worker
    (`id` int, `name` varchar(20));

    INSERT INTO completework
        (`id`, `workerid`, `checkerid`)
    VALUES
        (1, 2, 4),
        (2, 3, 5),
        (3, 4, 1),
        (4, 5, 2),
        (5, 1, 3),
        (6, 2, 4),
        (7, 3, 5),
        (8, 4, 1),
        (9, 5, 2),
        (10, 1, 3),
        (11, 2, 4),
        (12, 3, 5),
        (13, 4, 1),
        (14, 5, 2);

    INSERT INTO worker
        (`id`, `name`)
    VALUES
    (1, 'Anthony'),
    (2, 'Bill'),
    (3, 'Claire'),
    (4, 'Daniel'),
    (5, 'Emma');
```

I want to return results where the worker is either a worker or a checker, so I thought that I would need to union the two columns, but when I try to do this I get the error

```
Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

I have tried the below

```
    select
    workerid as wid,
    wn.name
    from  completework
    inner join worker wn on completework.workerid=wn.id 
    group by wid
```

The above just gets the workerid column

```
    select
    checkerid as cid,
    wn.name
    from  completework
    inner join worker wn on completework.checkerid=wn.id 
    group by cid
```

The above just gets the checkerid column

```
    SELECT DISTINCT workedonid FROM (
      SELECT checkerid workedonid FROM completework  
      UNION 
      SELECT workerid workedonid FROM completework
    )c
    ORDER BY workedonid ASC
```

The above gets an id from either column

```
    select
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT workedonid FROM (
              SELECT checkerid workedonid FROM completework  
              UNION 
              SELECT workerid workedonid FROM completework
            )c
        ) a,
    wn.name
    from  completework
    inner join worker wn on completework.checkerid=wn.id 
    group by a
```

In the above I was trying to work the above into a subquery but am getting an error, how can I get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT w.id AS wid, w.name
FROM worker w
INNER JOIN completework cw ON w.id IN (cw.workerid, cw.checkerid);
```

Check this [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cebce/18)

**OUTPUT**

```
| WID |    NAME |
|-----|---------|
|   2 |    Bill |
|   4 |  Daniel |
|   3 |  Claire |
|   5 |    Emma |
|   1 | Anthony |
```